# scikit learn: add lasso or ridge penalty only on subset of parameters

Tags: regression, lasso, scikit-learn

Is there a way of using the linear model api to add the lasso penalty for a subset of the parameters I am regressing? For example, consider a linear separable decomposition that I want to fit to some sparse data subject to smooth constraints in one of the (separable) dimension.

This question indicates that this is somewhat possible through R's glm.

[Is there LASSO type model in which only some of the regressors are regulated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62267/is-there-lasso-type-model-in-which-only-some-of-the-regressors-are-regulated)

Of course, a DIY method will not be too hard. The question is rather whether it is possible through the scikit learn api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a module for this purpose. You can take a look:

https://github.com/3zhang/Python-Lasso-ElasticNet-Ridge-Regression-with-Customized-Penalties

Answer (score 2):

<s>It is possible for ridge regression but not lasso as of scikit-learn 1.3.0.  Compare the docs on the penalty weight `alpha` in [`Ridge`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html), which does allow you to set an array of weights, vs [`LASSO`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso), which does not.</s>

I goofed.  Setting `alpha` as an array is for performing multiple regressions with the same predictors against different targets.  To do a ridge regression with different penalties on each coordinate of $x$, note that
$$
\|Ax-b\|^2 + \alpha \|x\|^2 = \left\|\left[\begin{matrix}A\\ \alpha I\end{matrix}\right]x - \left[\begin{matrix}b\\ 0\end{matrix}\right]\right\|^2.
$$

So to only apply alpha to certain coordinates you have to run a regular linear regression, but append the relevant rows of $\alpha I$ to $A$ and an equal amount of zeros to $b$.